# How do I run a 'job scheduler' on a LAMP stack?

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I have a simple website built using PHP. It is hosted on a Linux server.

I need to run a PHP script every night. How do I do this?

Will an 'open-source job scheduler in java' be able to run a PHP script?

Comment: Does cron work on LAMP? Do you have a link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several possibilities.

If you have shell access to the machine you can set up a scheduled task (cron job, http://www.scrounge.org/linux/cron.html) to execute your script either by the php command line  client or by a tool like curl or wget.

IF you don't have access to the shell on that machine there are several web sites that offer free cronjobs. Basically what they do is that you give them a link and the schedule when they should access your link. Just google for online cron job

Comment: I don't believe I have access to the shell 'on that machine' when it is for a hosted site, correct?

Comment: Usually you don't. But some hosting companies allow you to create cron jobs. If not there's a lot of sites like http://www.onlinecronjobs.com/